# using spring jdbc template for populating results

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I have two classes

```
class Deptartment{
  int deptid,
  String deptname;
  List<Employee> employees;

}

class Employee{

 int empid;
 String empname;
 int deptid;

}

Table: 
Department:

    deptid,deptname

Employee

    empid,empname,deptid

Query: select * from deptartment d,employee e where  d.deptid= e.deptid
```

Now how can i populate Department object using spring jdbc template?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To help Sean Patrick Floyd, here's his solution with a single query :

```
final Map<Integer, Department> departments = new HashMap<Integer, Department>();
this.jdbcTemplate.query(
    "select d.deptid, d.deptname, e.empid, e.empname from Department d inner join Employee on e.deptid = e.deptid",
    new RowMapper<Employee>() {
        public Department mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Integer deptId = rs.getInt("deptid");
            Department d = (Department) departments.get(deptId);
            if (d == null) {
                String deptName = rs.getString("deptname");
                d = new Department();
                d.setDeptId(deptId);
                d.setDeptName(deptName);
                departments.put(deptId, d);
            }
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.setEmpId(rs.getInt("empid"));
            employee.setEmpName(rs.getString("empname"));
            employee.setDeptId(deptId);
            d.getEmployees().add(employee);
            return employee;
        }
    });
List<Department> result = new ArrayList<Department>(departments.values());
```

It happens to be shorter and more efficient.

Comment: Could this whole code snippet be extracted in a separate class, which implements RowMapper<Employee>?

Comment: It would be nice if you could use ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance e.g.

ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Employee.class) to map the attributes as well as for your department without the need for rs.gets.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct support of this scenario in Spring currently. However, you can use [the following `MultipleRowMapper` class](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7698) proposed for inclusion into future versions of Spring.

Comment: isn't this doable with a ResultsetExtractor?

Comment: @abalogh: Obviously, you can do it manually as well, but the proposed class simplifies it.

Comment: You're right, I've checked the link, just was surprised you wrote 'no direct support', which at first I understood as 'not doable' :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do:

```
Department department = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
        "select deptid, deptname from Department where deptid = :deptid",
        new Object[deptid],
        new RowMapper<Department>() {
            public Department mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                Department department = new Department();
                department.setDeptid(rs.getInt("deptid"));
                department.setDeptname(rs.getString("deptname"));
                return department;
            }
        });
department.setEmployees(this.jdbcTemplate.query(
        "select empid, empname from Employee",
            new RowMapper<Employee>() {
                public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    Employee employee = new Employee();
                    employee.setEmpid(rs.getInt("emptid"));
                    employee.setEmpname(rs.getString("empname"));
                    return department;
                }
            });
```

Comment: So, instead of one query, you are executing n + 1 (n being the number of departements). I wouldn't call this a good solution.

Comment: @JB Nizet: of course it would be much more efficient with a join, but the Java side would get a lot more complicated and I'm lazy.

Comment: I wanted the code for retriving a department given a deptid, so there will be one department object containing a List<Employee>, can you please provide a code snippet for it

Comment: @akshay : then why did you specify a query returning all the departments with all their emmployees?