# Is it possible to fetch data from database MVC style using procedures?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, plsql

Sorry for a badly framed title question.

But basically if I have two classes , Employee and Address.
Employee has reference to an instance of Address.

```
Class Employee{
  @Id
  Integer id;

  @Column(name="Name")
  private String name;

  @Column(name="Address")
  private Id addressId;

  @ManyToOne(name="Address", referencedColumnName="ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
  private Address address;
}
```

now using spring-hibernate, 
when I execute something like `"Select * from Employee"` , it will fetch me not only each employee record but also the corresponding contained Address record.
Thats how hibernate does it . I don't only get the address Id but a whole data of address in each object of employee.
So I can do something like employee.getAddress().getName()

but the thing is due to some weird client requirement, we're forced to only use procedures in our code to access data and procedures in turn will call queries . So no direct query in our code.
but with procedures we won't be able to take advantage of this feature of spring-hibernate.

Is it possible that a procedure can do the same (return whole data of each employee in each employee object)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can use `RowMapper` for that. Your procedure should return joined data employee and address. Simple example with `JdbcTemplate`:

```
public List<Employee> getEmployees(){
    final String sql = "CALL employees_procedure";
    final List<Employee> employees = (Employee) jdbcTemplate.queryForList("CALL employees_procedure", new EmployeeRowMapper());

    return employees ;
}

public class EmployeeRowMapper implements RowMapper {
    public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Employee employee= new Employee ();
        employee.set(rs.getString("e.id"));
        ...
        return employee;
    }
}
```

Comment: what if two columns in a table have the same column , say ID ?? how then we would distinguish ? also my classes tend to be fairly nested sometimes.
In our project, we have say Employee has instance of Address has instance of State which has an country.
So I think we will still have a lot of filtering to do in our RowMapper instance
Is there any shorter way, though the one you suggested is the next best thing IMHO ! :)

Comment: **Also what if one employee is mapped to two addresses. how to address filtering and mapping in that case ?**

Comment: you should set table aliases like Employee e JOIN Address a, and then getInt("e.id") as I wrote. anyway when you query with hibernate it doing the same nested joins, so they would be in your procedure.

Comment: Ah yes missed that, then probably you should use ResultSetExtractor for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/6522544/2055854

Comment: sorry the link u gave had no example of ResultSetExtractor

Comment: Yeap sorry for that, but link also should suits you. Here you can find about ResultSetExtractor http://codeomitted.com/querying-with-jdbctemplate/ at the end

Comment: **what about cases where table is self-recursive, i.e a column in table points to primary id of some other row in the same table?**

Comment: when you do join you should always add aliases for tables, the same with self join select * from A a1 join A a2 on a1.parentId = a2.id

Comment: **In your above example I don't understand how the resultset returned by the procedure goes to the RowMapper implementation.
Also what if your procedure has one OUT parameter to return the resultset? then how is that resultset retrieved its not clear**

Comment: As you can see queryForList we put EmployeeRowMapper, it traverse through result set and maps each row to Employee object.

Comment: Thanks . I have selected ur answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Please look at [How to call procedures](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/)